If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ Is a countable set prove that $\exists$ a function $f$ such that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty \ \forall a \in A'$
I saw this problem If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ Is a countable set prove that $\exists$  a function $f: A\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty \ \forall a \in A'$. Where $A'$ is the set of limit points.
I tried to work on $\mathbb{R}$ and I couldn't find such function on a dense set. AI spent a lot of time on this problem and didn't mange to find any function like this on the rationals.

Another thing that I noticed is this function implies that there is no countable perfect sets because if there is every point of this will be mapped to infinity which contradicts the assumption of  $f: A\to \mathbb{R}$, am I right ?

An example of such an $f$ on the rationals would be the function $f(\frac{p}{q})=q$ where $p,q$ are coprime with $q>0$.

@S.L. I didn't think of that, Thank you very mach, I think now since $A$ is countable the is a $1-1$ mapping of $A$ to rationals and then applying your function, But is this enough to prove that "there is no countable perfect sets"

See my answer below

Do you happen to mean $\lim_{a\rightarrow x} f(a)$ for all $x\in A'$? Your function is apriori only defined on $A$. Also, you probably meant to assume $A$ to be countably infinite (the statement is not true for finite sets).

It was a typo $a\in A'$ not $x$, and does "countable" usually means infinite set
?

Countable usually means finite or in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$. The point being that you can enumerate those sets and thus "count" them.

If we were to consider such a function on a countable perfect $A$, it would have the remarkable property that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty$ for all $a \in A$. Such a function would be counter-intuitive, but unless you can think of a reason why such a function must not exist, you don't have any proof that such an $A$ does not exist. Note that, if the space is not complete, then such a function really can exist, see S.L.'s example over $\Bbb{Q}$. So, any reasoning you make will have to make some explicit reference to the completeness of $A$.

I thought I would post an answer in addition to my comment.
Although $f(\frac{p}{q})=q$ gives an example on $\mathbb{Q}$, we cannot compose this with a mapping from $A$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ unless this mapping preserves limit points (which may be possible, but more effort than it is worth).
Instead, consider the enumeration of $A=\{a_1,a_2,...\}$. Now define $f(a_r)=r$ and we are done, as we cannot have arbitrarily many $a_r$ close to some limit point for bounded $r$.
You mentioned that this implies that there is no countable perfect set. Not quite. The definition of $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ is the value $L$ such that $\forall \epsilon>0\exists\delta$ s.t. $0<|a-x|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. Notice that we do not allow $x=a$, so we are allowed to have isolated points, because $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not even exist for these points.
p.s. Note also that we are not allowed $f(x)=\infty$ for any $x\in A$ in order for $f$ to be a function into $\mathbb{R}$.
$f\to\infty$ is perfectly fine, however.
